# Trying to fetch data from Strapi API and post to HTML page using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, strapi

I am attempting to make a basic fetch request to the API I created with Strapi, then take the data and put it into my HTML page. So far I have been able to make the request show up on my page, but the results are showing up as undefined. Here is what that looks like:

Fetch Request:

```
function getSprites() {
    const div = document.getElementById('hello')
    fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/sprites')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.data.forEach(sprite => {
        div.innerHTML += `
        <li>${sprite.author}</li>
        `
      })
    })
  }

getSprites();
```

HTML:

`<div id="hello" class="sprite-container"></div>`

JSON Structure:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Example",
        "author": "Rosabelle",
        "submitter": "Exmaple",
        "createdAt": "2023-11-27T13:08:56.236Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-11-27T14:08:29.447Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-11-27T13:09:10.204Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": { "page": 1, "pageSize": 25, "pageCount": 1, "total": 2 }
  }
}
```

[image]

I am 100% sure it has to do with how I structured my fetch request, as I am having to say `data.data.forEach` rather than just `data.forEach` to make the request show up on the page. How should I change my fetch request so that instead of "undefined" the author "Rosabelle" shows up correctly in my HTML?

Answer (score -1):

Someone else managed to help me solve the problem and the answer was actually quite simple. I used `sprite.attributes.author` instead of `sprite.author` and that did the trick!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).